BAT1 Does Not Charge Past 4%
BAT1 is no longer charging past 4% on my Ubuntu machine; BAT0 is charging and discharging just fine. How can I solve this problem? I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad T460.


The picture says "Capacity 50%". That means the battery is old. Your laptop needs a new battery. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Thanks for your response. I thought 50% capacity means a battery could still work properly
